# get root domain from url Oracle sql regex_substr

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a query to get root domain from the urls as below :

```
 select REGEXP_SUBSTR(REGEXP_REPLACE('https://creditcards.chase.com/credit-cards/bp-credit-card.aspx',     '^http[s]?://(www\.)?|^www\.', '', 1), '(\.\w+)+') as domain from dual;
```

which returns the out put as : '.chase.com'

how can i ignore the first dot in outoput with regex in above query?

Note : I need only root domain, i.e, only 'chase.com'

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
select regexp_substr('https://creditcards.token.chase.com/credit-cards/bp-credit-card.aspx', '(^http[s]?://(www\.)?|^www\.)(\w+\.)*(\w+\.\w+)', 1, 1, 'i', 4) as domain from dual;
```